# Fade out and move up while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

The following script I am using fades out the div with the class .fader when scrolling down, it does not fads it out instantly but bit by bit while scrolling.

Everything is working, but how can I also make it so the div moves up while the fading effecting is taking place?

```
 //Fade Index on Scroll//
    var divs = $('.fader');
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        divs.css({ 'opacity' : (1 - st/300) });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop()>300) {
        $('.fader').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('.fader').show();
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top-section">
   <div class="content fader">
       <h1>I support and guide you through the process of <span>change</span>, <span>growth</span> and <span>personal evolution</span>.</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

        #top-section {
            color: #fff;
            height: 720px; 
            width: 1024px;

            position: relative; 
            padding: 100px 20px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #top-section .fader {
            width: 400px;
            padding-top: 170px;
            position: fixed;
        }

    }
```

Live preview: http://www.life-conversations.com/

Comment: could you please provide whole code with HTML? or create one JSFiddle

Comment: Just updated the question. Please take anther fresh look.

Comment: You should check out [skrollr](https://github.com/prinzhorn/skrollr).

Answer (score 1):

Please replace below line ...

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
```

with

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
```

You have to use `bind`...

Comment: I can go to jQuery's site and look it up but it would be helpful if you included the 'why'

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(".fader").animate({"opacity":(1 - st/300), "top": "-"+(st/300)},200);
```

**Edit:**

I don't really understand your desired effect but is this what you want?:

```
$(".fader").animate({"opacity":(1 - st/300), "top": "-"+st},50);
```

Comment: This send it up, but I want to follow the fading. Please look here: http://www.life-conversations.com/

Comment: Almost, I want it to be more sequential... so when you start scrolling the div will START to fade out sequentially WHILE you are scrolling, so if you scrolled up it will Start fading back in, and while it is doing that it will start moving up or down while fading - So sorry for the poor brief, do not know how to describe it :/

Comment: No problem...You should adjust it to your liking...Try to reduce the animation timing etc..